# Как определить какая по счету строка в .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Существует файл .txt в котором находятся такие данные как:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее эти данные переходят в словарь, где ключ это "One", значение "1", следующий ключ "Two", значение "2" и так далее. Далее эти значения сравниваются из другого словаря, где такие же ключи но другие значения. 
И при положительном сравнении (значение из первого словаря меньше чем из второго) должен запускаться другой файл. Проблема состоит в том, что файлы разные и зависят от положения ключа в .txt .

То есть при положительном сравнении ключа "One" должен запускаться скрипт 1.py. 
Однако вместо "One" может быть как и "Two", так и "Three", а запускать скрипт нужно не зависимо от ключа, зависит только положение в .txt. Как это можно сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: Тогда для чего вам `One`, `Two`, `Three`, если от них не зависит решение? И предоставьте, пожалуйста, более подробное описание того, как вы собираете обрабатывать данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете при чтении файла нумеровать строки:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for num, info in enumerate(f):
        print(num, info)
```